# What type of Spatial Indices supported by Apache Ignite?

Tags: ignite

As Apache Ignite has geospatial support, I just want to know what type spatial indexing technique supported by apache ignite? It is not clear in the following document.

https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/geospatial-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only supported spatial index in Apache Ignite is R-Tree.